# show Profile image of user that store in Firebase storage and save the link in the firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

im using flutter and i want to create a user profile with profile picture, i successfully store the image in the firebase storage and save the url link to the firestore in the collection with the field name of profileimage. now im facing a problem with the proper way of showing the profile picture from the firestore.

'Image.network("${loggedInUser.profileimage}",)' this code unfortunately now working for me.

heres my screenshot of firebase [image]

i would like to show the user profile pic along side their full name and email.

Answer (score 1):

Use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) for displaying images in a proper way.

use it in your code like this.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 80,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    imageUrl: loggedInUser.profileimage,
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error_outline),
                  ),
```